# The algorithm for the following analog controller => digital controller?

Tags: control, pid

I have found a continous control in the following form:

$$
u(s) = \left( K_{p} + \frac{K_{i}}{s} + K_{d} \frac{N}{1 + \frac{N}{s}} \right)e(s)
$$

but since I need it to "convert" in a digital control I need something like:

$$
y_{k} = y_{k-1} + q_{0}e_{k-1} + q_{2}e_{k-2}
$$

or everything that I can use in a digital way.
Is there any algorithm to achieve such transformation?
Actually the problem is the term $N$ in the equation. At first I thought that it was a simply PID controller but the N term is far from my understanding

Thank you very much and happy Christmas!!

Comment: Where have you found it, and why do you think it  is what you need? The derivative term looks unusual. What is N?

Comment: In this document [link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10846-013-9911-x) on page 43

Comment: Same question as Eugene Sh. This looks like a [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller), with an unusual term for the derivative term. The link you gave is not working.

Comment: The parameter N regulates the filtering on the derivative term to cut off high-frequency noise and to make the derivative feasible, of course. Read the [bible of PID](https://aiecp.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/1-0-1-k-j-astrom-pid-controllers-theory-design-and-tuning-2ed.pdf) (page 76) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [Tustin transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform) to get the bilinear mapping between s-domain and z-domain. You'll also find examples therein.

Once you're provided with the description of your transfer function in z-domain, it's straightforward to derive the formula in discrete time domain.

Given
$$
\frac{Y}{U}=\frac{b_0+\ldots+b_{m-1}z^{-(m-1)}+b_mz^{-m}}{a_0+\ldots+a_{n-1}z^{-(n-1)}+a_nz^{-n}},
$$

you'll obtain
$$
y_k=\frac{b_0u_k+\ldots+b_mu_{k-m} - a_1y_{k-1}-\ldots-a_ny_{k-n}}{a_0}.
$$

Comment: How should I deal with the $N$ term in the first formel?

Comment: Uhm, it seems you're not so familiar with PID control then... This is one of possible [reference](https://aiecp.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/1-0-1-k-j-astrom-pid-controllers-theory-design-and-tuning-2ed.pdf) (page 76). Before rushing headlong into the problem, always recap some useful pieces of theory :)